# Which command do you use to call a .exe in Visual Studio 2010 (c++)

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to build a form that installs only certain software when the 'Finish' button is pressed. I want to call a .exe file in Visual Studio 2010 so that it will run the .exe when the button is pressed.  I have tried the `start "";` command as well as the `CreateProcess ();` command and the regular c++ `System();` command. Nothing has worked up to this point.  Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us how you're trying to execute this other `.exe` in code? And your question is about C++, not Visual Studio.

Answer (score 6):

`CreateProcess` is the usual way. If it doesn't work, you're doing something wrong.

If it fails, you can call `GetLastError` for details on why it failed.

Comment: make sure you include the path correctly of the 'exe' no path indicates that it is in the same dir.

Comment: @corn3lius yup. But GetLastError will let you know if it can't find the exe.

Answer (score 1):

Try to call the executable with ShellExecute Windows' API.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx